# import android.content.pm.packageParser cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I am using the available code of PackageInstaller for testing my own application of installing and uninstalling the apk over the device.There is lots of error within Froyo for building this app. Please help me out of this.

See `PackageInstaller` code [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/donut;hb=refs/heads/donut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your answer explaining what error you get. I don't know if that works for non rooted phones, so take that into account.

There is a short tuto [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98).